# Footer doesn't reach end in chrome

Tags: html, css

This is how the footer looks in Firefox (how it SHOULD look), bordering on Firebug, filling out all of its height.

[image: Firefox]

And this is how it looks in Chrome:

[image]

So there is a ca. 30px high border before it reaches the bottom.

The (S)CSS code for the footer doesn't look all too spectacular:

```
.main-footer {
  background-color: $gray-base;
  color: $white-base;
  font-family: "Avenir";
}
```

I do give the footer an additional class, which adds a 170px high padding-top, which is there for an overlapping effect with another div. This code is not causing the 30px border, I already checked.

I also tried to give `body`and `html` a 100% height. Furthermore, I tried changing the `position` of the footer to `absolute` (which itself destroys the footer even more, fixing that with a 100% `width`) and playing around with bottom values, but the footer seems to disappear entirely.

I also just tried wrapping the footer in a `relative` positioned div, and positioning an inner div `absolute` and giving it a `bottom: 0;` value. Same result, footer not extending down entirely.

Kind of at the end with my ideas here, been a long time. If you need more information, I'll provide happily!

**EDIT**

Someone asked for a specific screenshot:

[image]

this is with `html { background-color: red; }` and `body { background-color: pink; }`

I did 2 additional screenshots which show the hover effects of the webtools. They don't hover over the red part, which seems interesting to me:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you able to provide a snippet which depicts your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by adding a specific height to the footer, which really is just a workaround, not a solution, I think.

```
.main-footer {
  background-color: $gray-base;
  color: $white-base;
  font-family: "Avenir";
  height: 265px;
}
```

The problem is, that I can't reproduce the bug in codepen.io or jsfiddle or whatever, which is why I struggle to provide more information. However, I answered my own question because it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this style to the body:

```
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
```

Usually on chrome there is this auto added whitespace on the body element.

Comment: ...You'll want to delete the period before "body" there friend ;)

Comment: sure, not a class

Comment: Thanks for your input. Just tried doing that (also tried it for `html`) but it doesn't do anything. I'm also pretty sure that this already part of bootstraps normalize process. At least `margin: 0`

Comment: Could you provide a link for a better understanding?

Comment: Please add this and provide a screenshot:

    html {background: red !important}
    body {background: pink !important}

Comment: Has the '2017 © bran..' element any `padding-bottom` or `margin-bottom` ?

Comment: no, it doesn't, if I give it a `margin-top: 25px`, the footer reaches the bottom. however there are 2 more columns in the footer and they wouldn't be on the same height, if I did this margin-top. If I give the `margin-top` to every column, the footer doesn't reach the bottom anymore.

Comment: How do you manage the layout of the two columns, are you using `float: left`?

Comment: I'd have to see the whole page. I can only think there's bottom margin on the footer, or negative margin somewhere above, or accidental padding on the body element. If I could inspect it in Firebug I could solve it, but I just don't have enough to go on to do it here :(

Comment: @mayersdesign that's alright. I got a workaround and will use it until i found a proper solution

Comment: @Treeindev There are 3 columns in the footer and bootstrap handles them, pretty much. It's the new 4.0.0-alpha6 (don't ask why we have to use this for productive environments, we just have to..), so I'm pretty sure it's handled via flexbox

Comment: The thing is that without a link to real case is difficult to guest what could be the problem.. sorry!

Comment: "It's the new 4.0.0-alpha6" - Well - all bets are off then haha, good luck